# how to get current song from playlist flutter just_audio

Tags: flutter, just-audio

1. I want to get all the details of the currently playing song
   which is played from a playlist.
2. I am using just_audio

Comment: It will be great if you show us what have have you tried till now, it will be easy for people to understand and guide you well.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```dart
player.sequenceState.currentSource
```

This will return the item from your playlist that is currently playing. As for "all the details", the `currentSource` is just the same audio source that you put into the playlist during your app's initialisation of the playlist, and so this contains all of the same details that were present when you created it. For example, if you added further details in the audio source's `tag` property, you'll be able to access those here as well.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to do the following :

```
player.sequenceState.currentSource
```

It just logs me : **Instance of 'ProgressiveAudioSource' ...**